# Writing M numpy data elements to a file with N elements per line

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a numpy array of size M and want to write all these elements to a text file
writing only N elements per line (N < M) and not write a newline at the end (i.e
when all the elements have exhausted). For example for M > N we could have:

```
2.000E-3   4.000E-4   6.4000E-5
7.500E-3   4.100E-4   6.4700E-1
2.100E-3   4.200E-4(no newline)
```

When the number ends, I must begin writing another number in similar format.I also need to take care of the case N=1 and M=1.

```
2.000E-3(no new line)
```

or   M < N case:

```
2.00E-3   4.000E-4(no newline)
```

All the elements are floats and must be written in scientific format with a delimiter of a number of four spaces (that number could vary).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to base a solution around this if your array is not huge:

```
import numpy as np

def output_array(a, m):
    n = len(a)
    n_mod_m = n % m
    if n <= m:
        last_row = a
        rows = []
    elif n_mod_m:
        last_row = a[-(n_mod_m):]
        rows = a[:-n_mod_m].reshape(n//m,m)
    else:
        last_row = a[-m:]
        rows = a[:-m].reshape(n-1,m)

    def s_row(row):
        return '   '.join(['{:8.3E}'.format(n) for n in row])

    if len(rows):
        print '\n'.join([s_row(row) for row in rows])
    print s_row(last_row),

a = np.array([0.002,0.0004,0.000064,0.0075, 0.00041,0.647,0.0021,0.00042])
output_array(a,3)
print '(no newline)'
output_array(a[:1],1)
print '(no newline)'

output_array(a[:2],4)
print '(no newline)'
```

which produces:

```
2.000E-03   4.000E-04   6.400E-05
7.500E-03   4.100E-04   6.470E-01
2.100E-03   4.200E-04 (no newline)

2.000E-03 (no newline)

2.000E-03   4.000E-04 (no newline)
```